# Convert UDP server to TCP

Tags: java, tcp, udp, server

I made a UDP server and now I want the server to be TCP, I don't like losing packets.

Will it be hard to reverse it to TCP or just a few things?
What things should I change to make it TCP? 
Can I still use all my packet classes?

I know I have to change the `DatagramSocket` but don't know to what.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at the [Oracle tutorials for TCP sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

Comment: This is one of the best link I have ever seen on same topic : http://phoenix.goucher.edu/~kelliher/s2011/cs325/feb25.html

Answer (score 0):

You should read about [TCP sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/) in Java, as Parker suggested.

If you want advanced functionalities for your server, such as session management, you can use a socket framework like [Apache MINA](https://mina.apache.org/) or [Netty](http://netty.io/).